# Filter for specific value, but use default value if it doesn't exist

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have an input schema that contains a list of phone numbers with a phone number type which looks as follows:

```
<phoneNumbers>
    <phoneNumber type="work">...</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber type="home">...</phoneNumber>
</phoneNumbers>
```

I only want to map a specific type of number, let's say 'work'. If a 'work' type phone number isn't available I need to fill in a default value.

This is what I start with:

[image: BizTalk mapping]

The problem I run into is that I can't get the default value to appear in the output if there is no 'work' phone number present.

Comment: XSLT!!!!!!!!!!! (only because I had to write 8 characters :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inline XSLT Scripting Functiod.

Suppose the source and destination structures look like this:

[image: Example map]

Inline XSLT would be something like this:

```xml
<workNumber xmlns:p="http://PhoneNumberMap.SourceSchema">
  <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="/p:Root/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type='work']" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$var:v1!=''">
      <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="'some default'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</workNumber>
```

Comment: I haven't been working with BizTalk for that long. Being a programmer, I should learn to not try to solve everything using Inline C# Scriptoids. :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using scripting functoid with  this.

```
public string setphonenumber(string work_number)
{
  string default = "123456789";
  if(work_number ="")
      return default;
  else return work_number;
```

}

Comment: I've had a solution similar to this. I still needed a cumulative concatenate for it to fully function the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone# have fixed length, you can string concatenate the default value in right side then feed to a string Left.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use a Not equal functoid to set your default value if it's different to "Work", and if it's equal to "work", you will have the source value in output

Answer (score 0):

Try to make map entire in xlst instead of using BizTalk map functoids. In the begin you will struggle with xslt, but after some time, you will love it!

I will not post the entire solution here, but I found a nice [Youtube post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffbP7FOoHM) that explains everything. It get's interesting at 3:00.